# How to count each week data in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I struggle with 2 problems.

**First problem is;** I want to count data each week and see total data. Total data is not correct. `W1` shows data for the last one week, `W2` shows data for the last two weeks etc.

Result:

| Fruit | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 6 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 25 |
| Banana | 7 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 32 |

The version I want:

| Fruit | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 6 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 13 |
| Banana | 7 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 22 |

Code:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(Eventtime,'W'))
    =to_number(to_char(SYSDATE-7,'W')) THEN 1 END) AS "w1"
COUNT(CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(Eventtime,'w'))
    =to_number(to_char(SYSDATE-14,'w')) THEN 1 END) AS "w2"
COUNT(CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(Eventtime,'W'))
    =to_number(to_char(SYSDATE-21,'W')) THEN 1 END) AS "w3"
...
Count (*) as Total
From XXX
where eventtime > sysdate-28
```

How can I get correct total?

**Second problem is;** I can't find `W5` data. I tried to add code below but `W5` shows `W1` data.

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(Eventtime,'W'))
    =to_number(to_char(SYSDATE-35,'W')) THEN 1 END) AS "w5"
where eventtime > sysdate-35
```

| Fruit | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 | w5 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 6 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 6 | 43 |
| Banana | 7 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 7 | 37 |

How can I get last 5 weeks data?

Comment: the primer problem, if you really want to sum the data of the weeks columns per fruit, it is simply sum the columns. I can't understand really the whole issue., The expected output is as easy as add all columns of w1+w2+w3+w4. Can you put the whole select you are trying and where this W1 ., W2 .. are coming from ?

Comment: Please, note that `w` mask is for week of month, that is between 1 and 5, so comparison of `w` of sysdate with `w` of some other date is pointless

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` to get last five weeks numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Use the ISO week (format `'IYYY-IW'`) for this.

```
select wk1, wk2, wk3, wk4, wk5, wk1 + wk2 + wk3 + wk4 + wk5 as total
from
(
  select
    fruit,
    dense_rank() over (order by to_char(eventtime, 'iyyy-iw') desc) as wk
  from fruits
  where eventtime > trunc(sysdate) - interval '35' day
)
pivot
(
  count(*)
  for wk in (1 as wk1, 2 as wk2, 3 as wk3, 4 as wk4, 5 as wk5)
)
order by fruit;
```

Comment: Awesome solution, thank you so much. This is the solution i needed . W1 gives between 20.09 and 26-09 dates. W2 gives 13.09-19.09 .. I'm appreciate.

Comment: There's no need to order the dates, you may calculate the difference between `sysdate` and `event_date` rounded to ISO week: `(trunc(sysdate, 'iw') - trunc(eventtime, 'iw')) / 7`

Comment: @astentx: This is a great idea I hadn't considered. Working with the truncated dates and calculating the week distance from them saves one step in the execution plan and is hence preferable.